# Powershell command $table.Columns.Add("NewFieldName") results in unexpected output to console

Tags: powershell

The following PowerShell script results in unexpected, and in my case unwanted, output to the console:

```
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$table.Columns.Add("NewFieldName")
```

Unexpected output:

```
AllowDBNull        : True
AutoIncrement      : False
AutoIncrementSeed  : 0
AutoIncrementStep  : 1
Caption            : NewFieldName
ColumnName         : NewFieldName
Prefix             : 
DataType           : System.String
DateTimeMode       : UnspecifiedLocal
DefaultValue       : 
Expression         : 
ExtendedProperties : {}
MaxLength          : -1
Namespace          : 
Ordinal            : 0
ReadOnly           : False
Table              : {}
Unique             : False
ColumnMapping      : Element
Site               : 
Container          : 
DesignMode         : False
```

Expected output:

My questions are:

1. Why?
2. How can I prevent this output from going out to the console with the rest of my output?

Comment: `[void]$table.Columns.Add("NewFieldName")`

Comment: @PetSerAl That did it. You're awesome. You should post an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: Add `[void]` like this

```
[void]$table.Columns.Add("NewFieldName")
```

**Why?** Because PowerShell tends to output the command's return value/object to the console (or whatever is receiving the output) by default.

**How can I prevent this output from going out to the console with the rest of my output?** Thank you to @PetSerAl for pointing out the solution of adding [void] to the left of the command.  This casts the command's return type to a [void] which will not output to the console.

After @PetSerAl pointed me in the right direction I found these pages that helped clear things up:

- [Into the [void]](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/void)
- Gotcha #10 in [PowerShell Gotchas](http://www.rlmueller.net/PSGotchas.htm)